# iOS - scaling/resizing a GLKView

Tags: ios, opengl-es, image-resizing, glkview, glpointsize

I'm rendering a GL_POINTS image in a `GLKView` with `width & height = .25`, meaning it has dimensions equal to a quarter of the screen's dimensions.
I would like to make its dimensions match the screen's ones, i.e. 4 times bigger than they are now.
I managed to do this setting the points' `gl_PointSize` to 4. (was 1.) and modifying the `x & y` appropriately, but this makes the rendering about 16% slower: is there a faster way to achieve the same result?